# Is this Jewish Neoplatonic idea heresy?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, heresy

**Context:**
I've noticed before that whenever I post anything about Neoplatonism in a Jewish context, such posts usually tend to get [downvoted to oblivion](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/136747/is-ruach-ha-kodesh-eternal-or-does-it-have-a-timespan-is-it-even-the-first-perf), and in general, such views are not very well received among most frum Jewish people that I've talked to.

However, it is well known that Neoplatonism had a [strong influence on Kabbalah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neoplatonism#:%7E:text=Jewish%20thought,-Main%20article%3A%20Jewish&text=In%20the%20Middle%20Ages%2C%20neoplatonist,light%20of%20their%20own%20monotheism.) and there were many Jewish philosophers who were Neoplatonists (e.g. Avicebron or Isaac Israeli ben Solomon). Of course, I think that for example, Avicebron's Neoplatonism is nonsensical (e.g. he believed that G-d, blessed be He, eternally and "unconsciously" emanates His own will through which He creates through many layers of emanation) - "Neoplatonism" is not a uniform philosophy and there are many differing views that all get grouped under the term "Neoplatonism".

---

**Formal question:**

**Is there anything heretical in Neoplatonic views? To be more specific, the idea that seems to get me the most flack is:** that G-d, blessed be He, can only directly produce one effect/creation which is necessarily the most perfect creation through which He creates everything else (the so-called "rule of one", which really comes from Islamic Neoplatonism ([qāʿidat al-wāḥid](https://brill.com/view/journals/orie/48/1-2/article-p123_5.xml?language=en)) **NOTE**: These ideas also have a parallel in Jewish thought - refer to Jewish Neoplatonism - Being above Being and divine emanation in Solomon ibn Gabirol and Isaac Israeli (2006, Cambridge University Press)). Are these ideas heretical?

**ADDITIONAL CLARIFICATION:**

G-d, blessed be He, can only directly produce one only creation which is necessarily the most perfect creation through which He creates everything else. Hence, G-d, blessed be He, does not directly create a tree. He is eternally creating the most perfect creation and through this most perfect creation, He directs the creation of trees.

Consider the following:

G-d
↓  eternally creates most perfect creation
First Intellect (an intelligent and willful most perfect first creation)
↓  from this point on, it mimics G-d to create another singular creation
Universal Soul
↓  (at this point, things can at least theoretically branch out according to some views, so the chain is no longer singularly linear)
......

So there is a chain of creation just like this. I provided some explanation for why this is the case in my link above where I talk about getting downvoted to oblivion.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148778/discussion-on-question-by-setszu-is-jewish-neoplatonism-heresy); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: What's the nafka mina?

Comment: I recommend adding sources that show that this is an idea that appears in Jewish neoplatonic writings.

Comment: The Maharal is extremely opposed to the idea that One cannot emanate multiplicity.

Comment: And influence is a tricky thing to evaluate if you can't prove that A saw the work of B. A lot of academics is just guesswork.

Comment: @RabbiKaii Did I not already outline it in the question? What's unclear?

Comment: @Harel13 I literally mentioned Solomon ibn Gabirol (Avicebron). See his Fons Vitae

Comment: @TheGRAPKE Can you please provide a source? What's his refutation of the idea?

Comment: I meant either linking to particular sections in their works or quoting them in your question.

Comment: @Harel13 Refer to the following: Jewish Neoplatonism - Being above Being and divine emanation in Solomon ibn Gabirol and Isaac Israeli (2006, Cambridge University Press). They outline it most clearly in the form that I put mine in, and they provide citations from Fons Vitae to support this, since not everything is always explicit

Comment: @N.T. "And influence is a tricky thing to evaluate if you can't prove that A saw the work of B. A lot of academics is just guesswork." - What does that have to do with anything? Oh, you mean the Kabbalah part? One can easily re-interpret that to simply mean that Kabbalists of the day simply wrote in the contemporary language that Rabbis of the day and philosophers of the day could understand (hence, why they explain Kabbalistic concepts through a Neoplatonic lens). So don't get overly caught up on that.

Comment: @Harel13 I edited it in, into the question

Comment: @שלום Why would it? I'm using "wider world" to mean a collection of all contingent existence and this first creation would be the most perfect contingent existence, essentially a servant of G-d, blessed be He, to whom G-d, blessed be He, can and does give orders to create other contingent existence. If you think of it as a member of this "wider world" collection, then it s not an intermediary, for G-d, blessed be He, directly created "the world", and just like we can create, so can that entity, except that that entity tends to follow G-d's word more perhaps I think?

Comment: @שלום How is it idolatry when I'm not worshipping it at all, I literally disregard it almost completely, its not much different than any other contingent existence except by the virtue of being more perfect due to ontological proximity to G-d, blessed be He. It has no power of its own at all, and that entity always depends on G-d, blessed be He, for every moment of its existence. When we say "without a partner", I imagine someone who is EQUAL to G-d, blessed be He, but that is logically impossible, hence its not idolatry, since this first creation is inferior to Him.

Comment: @שלום Unlike G-d, blessed be He, it is not pure perfection, It is simply the most perfect contingent existence, unlike G-d, blessed be He, who is literally pure perfection, even trasncending perfection itself and the root and source of all perfection. He has no equal. If you see my diagram in the question, it is completely and utterly subservient to G-d, blessed be He, for every moment of its existence and it has no power whatsoever on its own.

Comment: @שלום Yeah, that's what I said in one of the comments I think, I gave the analogy of G-d, blessed be He, creating a pen or like a servant and then using that creation to create further things.

Comment: @שלום In this understanding, G-d, blessed be He, still creates "the world" without intermediaries, and He still has no partners or anyone who could ever be equal to Him in any way whatsoever. Hence, there should be no contradiction with Maharal.

Comment: @שלום Oh, now that you bring it up, that could very well be a reference to it. Interesting, thanks!

Comment: "however, it is well known that Neoplatonism had a strong influence on Kabbalah" no, any "kabbalah" which is authentically Jewish is Torah and not a secular philosophy to be influenced by other philosophies.

Comment: @Dude Lol, then you're gonna be left with virtually no "Kabbalah" (at least as per the meaning of the term today). Read what I wrote in the comments (doesn't have to mean that Kabbalists stole ideas from philosophies, but rather expressed their ideas in philosophical language to the audience of the time so they could understand it better and btw Neoplatonism is not secular lol) + This is not up to debate (see research + my view that I just wrote before) + Didn't really ask tbh, stay on topic and don't get lost in the background context. Also, undo your downvote please.

Comment: @setszu https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A0%D7%A6%D7%97_%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%9C_(%D7%9E%D7%94%D7%A8%22%D7%9C)/%D7%9B%D7%9C_%D7%94%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8 ואומר אני כי הנמשך אחר זה הוא חטא גדול מאוד מאוד, כי שולל מאיתו יתברך בריאת כל העולם His refutation seems to be that God created the "beginning", and from the "beginning" comes the "many".

Comment: @TheGRAPKE I can't read Hebrew, and online translators are giving me weird stuff, so I will just go with what you say. But if we consider "the beginning" (quasi-"origin"?) to be this first most perfect creation, then multiplicity comes from it, because as an active intellect, it ponders both itself AND G-d, blessed be He. Also see what I wrote to שלום where I also show that the idea is not in contradiction with him if we are to understand that "the world" encompasses all contingent creations & that the first most perfect creation is like a servant or a tool, and has no actual power of its own

Comment: @TheGRAPKE All in all, I don't see how he refuted the idea. As a matter of fact, he seems to affirm in from my point of view, and my interpretation. There aren't any contradictions here.

Comment: @setzu bear in mind that most users on this site aren't philosophers or academics so I'd avoid using vocabulary that most people aren't familiar with like "ontological"

Comment: @MosesSupposes Gotcha, though in retrospect, I feel odd about calling it ontological proximity in the first place lol

Comment: @setszu not even remotely true. Kabbalah is Torah not goyishe philosophy

Comment: @setszu "Creation of a beginning with inherent multiplicity."

Comment: @TheGRAPKE Yes, the first most perfect creation necessarily has multiplicity

Comment: @Dude Ok, but my point is that most books that are considered Kabbalah today (e.g. Zohar) have been written in a context when such philosophical views were widespread among highly educated Rabbis, hence them using the language and perhaps concepts of the time to put it down into writing for more widespread use and to teach Kabbalistic messages.

Comment: Finding it funny that practically everyone has ignored that the conversation was moved to chat and is continuing here!

Comment: @setszu "Multiplicity is a function of creation."

Comment: @TheGRAPKE Bro that's literally what I'm saying, multiplicity intrinsically arises within the first most perfect creation as it ponders both itself and G-d, blessed be He. Its a function of creation. Multiplicity arises within the first and only "direct" effect.

Comment: @setszu that premise is factually incorrect. The zohar and other books of kabbalah are Torah. You are attempting to interject onto them an outside philosophy.

Comment: @TheGRAPKE The Maharal isn't attacking the proposition that one can only create one thing, only a specific variant of the proposition. In fact, the Maharal explicitly says מן השם יתברך אשר הוא אחד נשפע ממנו דבר אחד... מן האחד לא יושפע רק אחד. The Maharal's refutation is not "that God created the 'beginning', and from the 'beginning' comes the 'many,'" if those words are taken literally that is in fact the very idea he labels as חטא גדול מאוד מאוד. His exact words are ואחר כך הושפע עוד על הראשית (i.e. multiplicity comes from God continuing to emanate on the principle and not from the principle)

Comment: @ba Agreed. The Maharal seems to be saying the initial ראשית is an interface between Hashem and the בריאה.

Answer (score 0):

**First** there are different types and levels of "heresy". For example אפיקורס usually has one meaning (see סנהדרדין י:א) and the word מין might have another meaning.

**Second**, the obvious problem with your statement is whether you can limit what Hashem can do. It might be one thing to say that הקדוש ברוך הוא "decided" to create a creation that is somewhat perfect and from that to create creation.

You could argue a number of commentaries say exactly this for creation (or at least most things). See Hiyuli and Ramban Genesis 1:1. Nevertheless, I am not necessarily convinced this is a clear proof, since he considers a Spiritual substrate and Physical substrate being created - it is also unclear if these are "perfect" or rather hardly "physical" (which you can argue are more "perfect" or "one").

---

Your response (I'd like to focus on):

> Perfection is identical to Him, all-knowing is identical to Him, etc. and they're all identical to each other, with distinctions being mainly formal/virtual. Hence, if He has free will, which He does, His free will necessarily must also be perfect. Hence, He cannot actualize anything other than the most perfect creation because it would be a contradiction.
>
> If He had multiple choices, then either a) That would introduce composition within His essence, and hence, contingency, thus making Him not necessary existence and making something else be that (G-d forbid). or b) That would imply brute contingency which would contradict the principle of sufficient reason. Hence, He only makes one creation, and this creation is eternal and most perfect contingent creation
>
> This is not a limitation of power. Think of it this way: What would it mean that G-d, blessed be He, just arbitrary and randomly chooses to create whatever? If He can just bring imperfection when He could bring perfection, then how would in Jewish views He be all-good?

I wouldn't say that Hashem and his perfection are identical exactly, more like that we describe Hashem as perfect, but that attribution is actually limiting and therefore incorrect. I similarly wonder if "free-choice" in regard to Hashem is even close to a correct attribution.

Assuming there is some "choice" (as we envision it) - out of pure logic, his unlimited ability would allow him to create everything and anything. Ie: he cannot be limited because then there is no true free-choice and similarly, no true unlimited ability. It is standard Jewish thought to understand that Hashem could do everything and uses Angels and intermediaries for our benefit and for us to learn from; not because he is limited in some way.

Also what is created is here. Is it perfect or imperfect. According to you he created a perfect creation first, that created an imperfect one for us? If he is unlimited why can't he create a creation that must create something with no imperfections, or just create our universe perfect directly? Is that impossible? On the other hand, if this world is perfect there is no issue.

In Judaism there is a general idea that Hashem had a purpose for creation, and created the most perfect creation for that specific purpose. Ie: **The purpose was determinative of what was created more then Hashem's essence as you are stating**. Similarly the "imperfections" can serve that ultimate purpose, and are usually explained as only potentially there (ie: it is part of the system), and are actualized by man's free choice. **This is part of the mechanics and purpose of the world and therefore, part of the perfect creation. **

The heresy, if it exists, likely lies in the area where you are requiring this to be the only thing Hashem could create. That sounds quite problematic. Why do you need that component? I don't see any reason why that would be necessary. Similarly, **the anthropomorphic way you are describing Hashem as being perfect or how he chooses is not obvious to me in Judaism**, but once again not obvious to me that it is heresy.

For example: Why don't you state that this "perfect" creation served the purpose of creation for example, even if it means so we can understand his power, uniqueness and perfection? I prefer the Jewish version personally.

I am not an expert at heresy, it is possibly not heresy, but I think that your idea is not standard Jewish thinking. At least the way phrased here. Obvious heresy are things like: Multiple deities, The Torah not being given by Hashem etc....

I do suggest breaking the argument into components and re-asking it as separate questions if you want to know whether any component might be heresy.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 1) Neoplatonism primarily comes from Plotinus (c. 3th century CE), and not Plato. 2) By "most perfect creation", I mean, most perfectly actualiziable contingent (i.e. dependent) creation. Obviously, G-d, blessed be He, being the necessary existence, and fully independent, cannot be compared to anything - He is His own "category". But among the contingent creations like us, the first creation is the most perfect one. For (3) I will continue below

Comment: 3) Consider this: G-d, blessed be He, is necessary existence, so He cannot not exist. That is a part of His essence - eternity. And since He is one and His essence is one, all of His attributes are identical to each other and His essence. So perfection is identical to Him, all-knowing is identical to Him, etc. and they're all identical to each other, with distinctions being mainly formal/virtual. Hence, if He has free will, which He does, His free will necessarily must also be perfect. Hence, He cannot actualize anything other than the most perfect creation because it would be a contradiction

Comment: Because if He could for example, not exist (G-d forbid), then He would not be the necessary existence. And since He cannot contradict that attribute, He by extension cannot contradict any of His other attributes. So since He is all-powerful as there is nothing external to Him at that point, and nothing that could limit Him, He must actualize only one creation (since He is one, no multiplicity) which is necessarily the most perfect one

Comment: If He had multiple choices, then either a) That would introduce composition within His essence, and hence, contingency, thus making Him not necessary existence and making something else be that (G-d forbid). or b) That would imply brute contingency which would contradict the principle of sufficient reason. Hence, He only makes one creation, and this creation is eternal and most perfect contingent creation

Comment: 4) This is not a limitation of power. Think of it this way: What would it mean that G-d, blessed be He, just arbitrary and randomly chooses to create whatever? If He can just bring imperfection when He could bring perfection, then how would in Jewish views He be all-good? Think of Him creating something akin to a pen first to write everything with, or something like how when humans use a leaf in order not to crush smaller creations like ants to help them bc they're so powerful. Its similar like this. Its G-d, blessed be He, exercising maximal goodness, and protecting other smaller creations.

Comment: @setszu I have responded in post to avoid comment garble.

Comment: @setzu I don't think that logic holds up.  If I understand correctly, you are saying that if He is perfect then His creations must be perfect and therefore He can only create a single one, because that implies imperfection otherwise?  2 problems with that logic - 1) I don't see why He can't have a need of multiple creations for different purposes - eg. a "perfect hammer" can't cut wood because that isn't what it is supposed to do, and a "perfect saw" can't hammer nails in for the same reason.  2) If that logic were true then the perfect creation couldn't create more than 1 other creation too?

Comment: @msj121 given the nature of the subject, it would be very good if you add many sources to this answer

Comment: @MosesSupposes That's not really the main reasoning. Assume G-d, blessed be He, can originate more than 2 effects directly. This either implies a) Composition within Himself (His essence) or b) Brute contingency. If a) is true, then that's not G-d, blessed be He. If b) is true, you have a self-refuting idea. But also, the first effect must be the most perfect existence in an objective sense, and not only a "localized" perfection as I'd call it. Also for the logic above, I just have a question for you. Do you agree that humans in their best state, are more perfect than a piece of rock is?

Comment: @MosesSupposes Like, there are many many many reasons for this, I can't put them all here. Research "qāʿidat al-wāḥid" or the "rule of one" or the Neoplatonic "From One, only One comes"

Comment: @setzu I'm getting a bit lost with the philosophical terminology again.  I presume that "composition within Himself" means that He would be composed of multiple different things, but I don't know what Brute contingency means and a quick Google didn't answer that!  In any case, I'm not following your argument.  I think I'd probably say the rock is more perfect, because a human is inherently flawed, but a rock is far simpler and can easily be a perfect rock, but then it would really depend on your definition of perfection!

Comment: @setzu I've read up on it a little more and still think that the logic doesn't work for the reasons I gave above, but then I'm an engineer, not a philosopher!  It does occur to me that a possible neat solution is that there is actually only 1 thing that exists, but that it just loops through time over and over, so every photon is the same photon, every particle is made up from it multiple times looped over and over, and that it is made up of the same thing that non-physical entities are.  However, I don't actually see any need for such a theory, as neat as it is

Comment: @MosesSupposes stop re-inventing quantum physics https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-electron_universe

Comment: @RabbiKaii Ah, I might have heard that before and that was what I was thinking of, although I'm not talking about just electrons, or even just limiting it to the physical Universe, and I was proposing it as a solution to a completely different problem (even though I don't think it is one that exists!)

Comment: @setszu the root of your problems, it seems, is the idea that G-d cannot not exist. G-d can choose to not exist and succeed at it, and yet He would exist; simultaneously existing and not existing, because G-d **can** redefine logic. Likewise, any other "can't" statement attributed to G-d is incorrect. Logic does not limit G-d. The common sense of every description in kabbalah regarding Divine mechanics and spiritual "rules" (such as why G-d "had to" make something a certain way) is that G-d picked a vector space (logic) for us and then chose to operate within it 99% of the time.

Comment: @EthanLeonard It means literal incoherence/impossibility. Judaism doesn't "believe" in literally/logically impossible things. G-d choosing to not exist is an impossibility and is theoretically nonsensical. Pls read literally any philosopher on this (Mulla Sadra, Ibn Sina, Aquinas, probably even Rambam, etc.). G-d cannot "not exist" for that would be a contradiction (impossibility). And if He cannot contradict His eternity (as an attribute), then He can't contradict any other of His attributes. Hence, His will must also be = to His perfection and so He can only create most perfect thing

Comment: @EthanLeonard 2nd of all, if this is what "Kabbalah" states, then "Kabbalah" is wrong and can be logically refuted

Comment: @EthanLeonard "logic" here is simply explaining whether something is coherent at all. To say that He does not abide logic has nonsensical implications and is like saying "Can I drink a Wednesday" - completely incoherence. I think that one can prove that some laws of logic are also directly a part of G-d's essence eg the law of identity (p≡p or in propositional logic p→p) since He keeps His identity constant and by proxy, sustains the identity of everything else at any moment, so He can also be thought to be an active agent who is pure necessary "logic" the same way He is "perfection".

Comment: @EthanLeonard In other words, through His perfect essence, He is the one keeping coherence to the world at all. And I don't think that this is a limitation at all, because He is the one determining by Himself what He wants to do without any external limitations (and if you think about it, this is what a truly "free agent" is), and since He is absolutely perfect, He can only eternally actualize 1 "direct most perfect creation". Anything else would be a contradiction, and thus total incoherence.

Comment: @EthanLeonard I already responded to this, but I just have to point out how nonsensical this sentence sounds "simultaneously existing and not existing, because G-d can redefine logic.". Btw are you aware of modal logic? And this btw would not be G-d. "Likewise, any other "can't" statement attributed to G-d is incorrect" - Do you have any proofs for this statement or the one above? Your issue sounds like you think that we are ascribing "limitations to G-d" and this sounds wrong to you, so you collapse into absurdity and nonsense. But I already showed that this is not a "limitation".

Comment: @MosesSupposes Brute contingency is an existence/thing that is contingent (in this case, "dependent") on something other than itself, which is also a "brute fact", meaning that it intrinsically lacks any explanation/intelligibility/reason/cause/grounding (depends on the version of the principle of sufficient reason) for its existence. This does not mean that just because we cannot explain something right now, or maybe even EVER as humans, that it intrinsically and impossibly lacks *any* intelligebility/cause/etc.

Comment: @MosesSupposes In the most extreme case of such "understanding", however, this could even imply that something could pop into existence without G-d's own control/wish, and that perhaps not even G-d, blessed be He, could fully "understand" it which is nonsensical. Anyway, loop up what a "brute fact" is and what the principle of sufficient reason and the related "principle of causality" is if you want to know more.

Comment: @setszu it is nonsensical. It is also not my invention at all. This is a well discussed concept called נמנה הנמנעות, and it's present plainly in the Ark in the קדש הקדשים, where it did and did not take up space (Yoma 21a; Megillah 10b; Bava Batra 99a). See http://surl.li/lqehw for more about that example. Besides that, you can see שו"ת הרשב"א חלק ראשון תשובות תי"ג-תי"ח, and פלח הרימון, שיר השירים קכו, א, for a direct address of this topic. Also ספר החקירה לצמח צדק לד ב. The Lubavitcher Rebbe also said this many times. Also, I think your many questions are valid attacks on the opposing view.

Comment: @EthanLeonard Thx but can you elaborate on this? Something existing but not occupying space as per Bava Batra 99a, Yoma 21a, etc. as shown by the concept in the ark, is not the same thing as saying that it exists and doesn't exist. In this context, it's saying that something exists but "that the cherubs stood miraculously and did not **occupy any physical space**". Existing but not occupying space is not the same as existing and not existing (contradiction) unless one commits equivocation fallacy for the word "existence" & incorrectly makes it mean the same thing for two different categories.

Comment: @EthanLeonard In other words, to say that something exists and doesn't exist is a product of imprecise and improper language, so I still reject this concept, including the other things you cited (Rashba, Tzemach Tzedek, Lubavitcher Rebbe, etc.) and/or their interpretations and they wouldn't necessarily apply here properly and coherently

Comment: @setzu from doing a bit of reading up, as far as I can tell, the whole "God can only create one thing" is not a core tenet of Neoplatonism, but only specific schools of thought within it, so I feel like we're not really dealing with the question that you asked? In any case, I feel like there are major assumptions being made with the logic here which I'm not at all convinced are correct.  I think I understand what you mean by a brute contingency now, but I don't understand what that has to do with anything.

Comment: @setszu I think it's possible you may have missed a nuance of the article and sources. Those Gemaras say that it **did not occupy any physical space and did** occupy physical space. It could be measured by artisans in the קדש הקדשים and would have dimension. Yet, measuring the distance between it and the walls would still measure half the total width of the room. This is manipulation of logic, which is נמנה הנמנעות. Between wall and ארון, your tape measure says 10. Then to the other end of the ארון, it says 20. Then to the other wall, it says 20, but there's 10 between wall 2 and ארון.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you if it is heretical, but I can give you some information from the chassidic approach that might help you determine how to proceed with the question, and what is needed to find the answer.

The chassidic teachings record that the great Torah leaders of each generation passed on an esoteric tradition. There are many notable events in this tradition but the key ones are Adam Harishon received the secrets of creation from an angel, the Avot were in the chain that received that and added more, then Moshe was taught where it all is in the Torah when he received it at Sinai, and R Shimon Bar Yochai completed it, seeing with a "clear lens" and becoming the final and greatest teacher of the full secrets of the Torah.

After he passed, the knowledge went underground and was only passed among the selected few. We have works from the Geonim and the chassidic masters teach us that they recorded their knowledge in very encrypted form in these works. The subsequent generations enclothed the teachings in *philosophy*.

This is where I am getting to. The philosophical teachings we have, such as Maimonides, according to the chassidic view, contain within them, *secretly*, the esoteric teachings. The Rambam "hid and scattered the teachings in pieces throughout his writing", in the form of Aristotelian philosophy, and the mystical tradition he was working from might have even been partial. Many great chassidic Rebbeim, including from Chabad and Ishbitz, who were all great and holy Kabbalists, spilled a lot of ink showing how Rambam's teachings contain these ideas.

R Gershon Henoch writes in his introduction to Beit Yaacov (from chapter 15 there are a few chapters on showing Kabbalah in Rambam) that someone trying to understand the secrets of the Torah from philosophy is akin to someone trying to work backwards from the effect to the cause; a task that is impossible to do completely, if even partially (and uses derivation from argument, which is the exact opposite of *Kabbalah*, I.e. *received* wisdom). In the case of philosophy, it's even harder because philosophy, especially the type of Grecian rational philosophies we are talking about, aren't able and aren't even trying to convey anything of the superrational, which is of course where you need to go when you are discussing things that come *before* intellect! Thus, the only way to learn the secrets of the Torah today is to do so through the teachings of the Zohar, which is the work of Rabbi Shimon Bar Yochai who as we said is the greatest and final teacher of the complete mysteries of Torah. The Zohar is the cause, rather than one of the "effects", going by the above analogy.

R Henoch also points out that the mysteries of creation that are hidden in the teachings of philosophy are muddled with non authentic traditions. In today's day when we have the Zohar and hundreds of works based on it, elucidating the inheritance of Yaacov: the secrets of the Torah, by great holy Chachamim and Rebbeim, including the Arizal, and all the Chassidic Rebbes and great Kabbalists of the last 500 years, there are only very few who seriously still try to unpack the esoteric teachings of the Kabbalah from the enigmatic works of the period when Kabbalah was "underground", including the philosophical works. Still fewer who would allow it, let alone recommend it.

So, according to this traditional approach I have brought, the recommendation would be that if you want to understand the secrets of the Divine, you should *start* with authentic teachings based on the Zohar, and nowadays there are many options and styles that might suit you, if you are diligent in your search (you said the Neoplatonic ideas help you understand these things and speak to you, which might imply that you've not had such an experience studying the esoteric from traditional Zoharic sources).

It would be very nice if a very learned person will come and just answer your question with a yes/no and neat explanation but I think from what I've laid out here, it seems that there are a number of barriers that might prevent that happening, including the point that rational philosophies are often *just not enough and not fully capable of* containing complete Divine truths, as well as being a very controversial and dangerous way to approach gaining this Divine knowledge in a "clear lens" way. Philosophy is a tainted and muddled, inadequate esoteric source, and is at best a clothing of encoded information about Divine truth and therefore yes, there are many barriers that may make this question "off topic" in the traditional approach :) As I said, a lot of writing has been written on the Rambam's ways of enclothing Divine esoteric wisdom in philosophy, it might be of interest to you to follow that up, but it is unlikely you'll find the same amount and the same calibre of work done on the Neoplatonic works. You've citied so far only contemporary scholars in a single academic work making that claim. Surely their work would cite some traditional sources who spoke about the Neoplatonic theory? If so, you should go and learn those, of course! Or cite them in the question for us. If there aren't any, then all the more you should consider the recommendations I am laying out here.

I recommend reading his whole introduction to Beit Yaacov, but especially chapters 13 onwards for a few chapters. It is in his work Sha'ar HaEmuna VeYesod HaChassidut, and can be found in English on sefaria. Hatzlacha.

Comment: one time i scribbled with a ballpoint pen on a piece of tissue paper, and showed it to my brother, saying; "look, i found a manuscript from moshe rabeinu!".

Comment: @eliezer incredible, did the sucker buy it?

Comment: apparently it depends on whether he finds the scribbles along with the associated claims useful.

Comment: Note that the OP specifically mentions answers from the Kabbalah as sought